# Unable to debug google SIGN IN on vscode

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-oauth, react-google-login

I am trying to integrate Google sign in on my react js application. Well the i am using react-google-login package to implement it. Its working perfectly fine when i am launching it via npm start. But the when i am launching my application via a debugger in VSCode and trying to do google sign in it is throwing following error.

[image]

And my launch config is

[image]

I have already tried, allowing unsecured application to sign in on google settings for my id.
[image]

EDIT: Adding Sign in code

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import {} from "dotenv/config";

const LoginGoogle = () => {
  const onSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log("Login Sucess currentUSer " + JSON.stringify(res));
  };
  const onFailure = () => {
    console.log("Login Fail");
  };
  const value = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_O_AUTH_CLIENT_ID;

  return (
    <div className="pb-5">
      <GoogleLogin
        // clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_O_AUTH_CLIENT_ID}
        clientId={value}
        buttonText="Login this shit"
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onFailure={onFailure}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        className="mt-5"
        isSignedIn={true}
      ></GoogleLogin>
    </div>
  );
};
export default LoginGoogle;
```

Comment: Note this is signin not Oauth.  Can you post your code please.   Try setting it to run https.

Comment: @DaImTo, right my mistake, i have updated my post with the code. and sure let me try it on https

Comment: Welcome to stack Please post code not images of code.

Comment: Sure will keep in mind for next time.